# Send a message to each recipient in a list in a spreadsheet file

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to handle multiple message objects.

Ultimately, I want to send a message to a list of recipients in a spreadsheet file.

```vb
Dim w As Outlook.Application
Dim wInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Dim count, x, msgnum As Integer
' Handle Microsoft outlook
Set w = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err = ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING Then    ' Open new instance if none is running
    Set w = New Outlook.Application
    wInbox = w.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
End If
    
'Count number of emails required
count = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
msgnum = wInbox.Items.count
For x = 1 To count
    Set objOutlookMsg = w.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    msgnum = wInbox.Items.count
Next x
```

-------Edit---------
What if I handle the code like this?

````vb
Dim w As Outlook.Application
Dim wInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    
Dim count, x, msgnum As Integer
' Handle Microsoft outlook
Set w = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err = ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING Then    ' Open new instance if none is running
    Set w = New Outlook.Application
End If
wInbox = w.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
'Count number of emails required
count = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
msgnum = wInbox.Items.count
For x = 1 To count
    Set objOutlookMsg = w.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    msgnum = wInbox.Items.count
Next x
```
````

Comment: i can't see anything really unusual in your code. Where does the code stops ? or where doesn't it work ?

Comment: Your code will fail if Outlook is already running, since you're only setting wInbox when you start a new instance.  Can you provide more details?  You want to sent the same message to multiple recipients?  Can you just send one message with all recipients in the To (or Bcc) field?

Comment: To be more specific, I'm having trouble handling objOutlookMsg object to work with multiple messages.

Comment: If it's the same message you're sending then you only need the one...  If it's a different message to each recipient then you should create and send each message in turn - no need to create a whole set of new messages up-front.

Comment: @Tim Williams: I want to send the same message (with slight differences) to multiple recipients. See my fixed code in the edit.

Comment: @staginator - see my code below.  That should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
Sub TestOutlookSend()

    Dim w As Outlook.Application
    Dim wInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim rngAddr As Range, recip As String

        Set rngAddr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

        Set w = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        Set wInbox = w.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

        Do While rngAddr.Value <> ""
            recip = rngAddr.Value

            Set objOutlookMsg = w.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With objOutlookMsg
                .To = recip
                .Subject = "Hello " & recip
                .Body = "A message for" & recip
                .Send
            End With

            Set rngAddr = rngAddr.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What if I don't want to send them immediately, but leave them open inactively?

Comment: I think I got confused on which message the code is looking at for obOutlookMsg, that's all.

Comment: It's creating a new message each time through the loop, but creating the next one should leave the previous one open.

Comment: Would I have to call a particular function to make the new messages visible in Windows?